# Listing an array of data ordered by how often they appear

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've been trying to use PHP to check how common a word appears in a particular array of data that I have, the example being:

```
array(
    "foo",
    "foo",
    "foobar",
    "foo",
    "foobar",
    "apples"
)
```

and then turning this array into an associative array based on how often the word appears, it doesn't even need to be an associative array, it could also be placed into a table format or text:

```
array(
    "foo"=>"3",
    "foobar"=>"2",
    "apples"=>"1"
)
```

or

"foo appears 3 times",
"foobar appears 2 times"

I apologise for not having much being tested around how I can solve this, apart from I'm really unsure where to start by doing this. I can't see how I can put an array in substr_count() to count individual words in the array (I can't have foo being equal to five because of two foobars which appear) and I'm not sure what other method i can use to approach a solution

Comment: Google: `PHP array count values` (Keep it simple; Just use keywords for searching)

Comment: Wow that's amazing! @Rizier123

Comment: array_count_values($array).